# Existence of a linear map between two binary vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to label all binary vectors $\mathbf{s}$ of length $N$ with exactly $k$ entries equal to $1$ into binary vectors $\mathbf{b}$ of length $l = \left \lceil \log_2 \binom{N}{k} \right \rceil$. This is to save space in an algorithm and the logic behind labeling does not matter as long as different states have different labels.

Now I am wondering: Is there a linear way to label $\mathbf{s}$ in $\mathbf{b}$, i.e. $\exists A, \mathbf{r} : \mathbf{s} = A\mathbf{b} + \mathbf{r}$ ?

If there is one, how to construct the matrix $A$ and vector $\mathbf{r}$ ? If not, how to disprove it (or at least some intuition on why it cannot be done)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? That is, for what values of $N$ and $k$ have you tried to find $A$ and $r$? The $k=1$ case is probably doable, but $k=2$?

Comment: @Somos The first nontrivial case I've run into is $N=4, k=2$.